# MongoDB .NET Driver - StartsWith & Contains with loosely typed data

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I can use the following for exact matches on loosely typed data in MongoDB:

```cs
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(con);
IMongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase("mydb");
var profile = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("profiles");
var query = profile.AsQueryable();

var results = query.Where(x => x["first_name"] == "john").Take(10);
```

But how do I use the same approach to do `StartsWith` and `Contains`?

I tried:

```cs
var results = query.Where(x => x["first_name"].AsString.Contains("john")).Take(10);
```

But I get the error:

> Method 'Boolean Contains(System.String)' declared on type 'System.String' cannot be called with an instance of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'

How do I use these filters?

Comment: I get errror: BsonValue does not contain definition `contains`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast to string instead of using `AsString`, it should work:

```cs
var results = query.Where(x => ((string) x["first_name"]).Contains("john")).Take(10);
```

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB .NET Driver provides [LinqExtensions.Inject](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Linq_LinqExtensions_Inject__1.htm) that you can inject `FilterDefinition` into a LINQ where clause.

> Start with Filter

```cs
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>
    .Filter
    .Regex("first_name", "^" + "john" + ".*");

var results = query.Where(x => filter.Inject())
    .Take(10);
```

> Contains Filter

```cs
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>
    .Filter
    .Regex("first_name", "john");

var results = query.Where(x => filter.Inject())
    .Take(10);
```